# Sorting an Array so that all elements with Some are in front

Tags: .net, arrays, sorting, f#, option-type

I have an F# record type (`Request<'a>`) defined with one of its field as an `('a -> bool) option`. At some point, I have an array of this record type, and would like to have it sorted so that all of the ones with `Some ('a -> bool)` would be first (lowest index), and all the ones with `None` would be last (highest index).

I have tried doing the following, but this does not seem to work as I have some of them that are in the middle/end of the array:

```
let sort (req1:Request<'a>) (req2:Request<'a>) =
    if req1.ResourceCondition.IsSome
    then
        -1
    else if req2.ResourceCondition.IsSome
    then
        1
    else
        0

let reqArray = Array.sortWith sort fifoArray
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your comparing function has flawed logic. Try to run it step by step. Look: if both `req1` and `req2` are `Some`, then your function will return -1. Not what you'd expect, is it?

I would rather express it in terms of pattern matching:

```
let sort (req1:Request<_>) (req2:Request<_>) =
    match req1.ResourceCondition, req2.ResourceCondition with
    | None, Some _ -> 1
    | Some _, None -> -1
    | _ -> 0
```